# Git show vs Git log --numstat output difference

Tags: git

I'm comparing git show and git log with the same options.  I get different results on different commits.  I haven't really dug through the docs yet to figure out why this is, but I'm guessing it has to do with how each command interprets the revision list and what the commit graph looks like?  Eg, demo on FFmpeg:

Case 1 git log:

```
> git log -n1 --numstat --format='%H' 00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837
00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837
```

Case 1 git show:

```
> git show -n1 --numstat --format='%H' 00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837
00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837

4       0       libavcodec/mpegaudiodecheader.c
```

Case 2 git log:

```
> git log -n1 --numstat --format='%H' 001d668d40b5f87d19271c7d5521368b5187425b
001d668d40b5f87d19271c7d5521368b5187425b

2       5       libavformat/dvenc.c
2       6       libavformat/gxfenc.c
5       0       libavformat/internal.h
2       5       libavformat/movenc.c
2       5       libavformat/mxfenc.c
7       0       libavformat/utils.c
```

Case 2 git show:

```
> git show -n1 --numstat --format='%H' 001d668d40b5f87d19271c7d5521368b5187425b
001d668d40b5f87d19271c7d5521368b5187425b

2       5       libavformat/dvenc.c
2       6       libavformat/gxfenc.c
5       0       libavformat/internal.h
2       5       libavformat/movenc.c
2       5       libavformat/mxfenc.c
7       0       libavformat/utils.c
```

Basically, I'm confused as to why for case 1, log omits the changed files (`libavcodec/mpegaudiodecheader.c`), while show includes them, and then in case 2, the output is identical.

For reference:

```
> git diff --numstat 00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837 00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837^
0       4       libavcodec/mpegaudiodecheader.c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Joseph K. Strauss**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37038767/1256452) is correct (this is a merge commit) but not quite complete.  The missing bits of information are scattered within the Git documentation and source, which is why they are so hard to find.

First, `00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837` [really is a merge commit](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837).  Its two parents are `d832020bd853f84b96a3fdf3e0a385d8492ec8c8` and `fcbcc561e0fdc95a7dd48b92db53846726aec27e` (we don't need to know their exact numbers, but might as well record them to show its "merge-ness").

[The `git show` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html#_combined_diff_format) gives us a hint:

> Any diff-generating command can take the `-c` or `--cc` option to produce a *combined diff* when showing a merge. This is the default format when showing merges with [git-diff(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) or [git-show(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html). Note also that you can give the `-m` option to any of these commands to force generation of diffs with individual parents of a merge.

What is missing here is a description of `-c` and `--cc` themselves, which is nowhere to be found in either of the two linked manual pages, but *is* in that for [`git diff-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html).  Before we go there, however, it is worth going to [the `git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_diff_format_for_merges), where we find this:

> "git-diff-tree", "git-diff-files" and "git-diff --raw" can take `-c` or `--cc` option to generate diff output also for merge commits. [snip example]
>   **Note that *combined diff* lists only files which were modified from all parents.**

(boldface mine, but it really is very important; we will see it again in a moment, where I will use bold again).  Now we can jump back to [`git diff-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html), where we find a the actual descriptions for `-c` and `--cc`:

> `-c`
>         This flag changes the way a merge commit is displayed (which means it is useful only when the command is given one *tree-ish*, or `--stdin`). It shows the differences from each of the parents to the merge result simultaneously instead of showing pairwise diff between a parent and the result one at a time (which is what the `-m` option does). Furthermore, it lists **only files which were modified from all parents**.
>
> `--cc`
>         This flag changes the way a merge commit patch is displayed, in a similar way to the `-c` option. It implies the `-c` and `-p` options and further compresses the patch output by omitting uninteresting hunks whose the contents in the parents have only two variants and the merge result picks one of them without modification. When all hunks are uninteresting, the commit itself and the commit log message is not shown, just like in any other "empty diff" case.

Note that this tells us that `--cc` is the default for `git show` but says nothing about `git log`.  It turns out that `git log` defaults to just suppressing merge diff output entirely, while `git show` sets `--cc`.  The former does not seem to be documented anywhere, but is found in the Git source, in `builtin/log.c` and `revision.c`:

```
[revision.c]
void init_revisions(struct rev_info *revs, const char *prefix)
{
        memset(revs, 0, sizeof(*revs));

        revs->abbrev = DEFAULT_ABBREV;
        revs->ignore_merges = 1;
        revs->simplify_history = 1;
[snip]
```

This sets up the default action to ignore merges (`revs->ignore_merges = 1`), for all commands; commands that want to work on merges need to clear the flag (this is also noted in `Documentation/technical/api-revision-walking.txt`).

Both `git show` and `git log` (along with several others) are implemented in `builtin/log.c`, which contains this, in part:

```
static void log_setup_revisions_tweak(struct rev_info *rev,
                                      struct setup_revision_opt *opt)
{
        if (DIFF_OPT_TST(&rev->diffopt, DEFAULT_FOLLOW_RENAMES) &&
            rev->prune_data.nr == 1)
                DIFF_OPT_SET(&rev->diffopt, FOLLOW_RENAMES);

        /* Turn --cc/-c into -p --cc/-c when -p was not given */
        if (!rev->diffopt.output_format && rev->combine_merges)
                rev->diffopt.output_format = DIFF_FORMAT_PATCH;

        /* Turn -m on when --cc/-c was given */
        if (rev->combine_merges)
                rev->ignore_merges = 0;
}
```

This is where the combined diff options, if selected, enable showing merges at all.  Meanwhile, for `git show`:

```
static void show_setup_revisions_tweak(struct rev_info *rev,
                                       struct setup_revision_opt *opt)
{
        if (rev->ignore_merges) {
                /* There was no "-m" on the command line */
                rev->ignore_merges = 0;
                if (!rev->first_parent_only && !rev->combine_merges) {
                        /* No "--first-parent", "-c", or "--cc" */
                        rev->combine_merges = 1;
                        rev->dense_combined_merges = 1;
                }
        }
        if (!rev->diffopt.output_format)
                rev->diffopt.output_format = DIFF_FORMAT_PATCH;
}
```

So `git show` checks whether `-m` was specified.  If not, it turns on `-m` internally, then turns on `--cc` unless there were any of three explicit options: `-c`, `--cc`, and `--first-parent`.  The first two make sense (don't override the user's setting) but the third is just weird.  (Perhaps it is there to avoid causing problems later, if we go to do a combined diff but only have yanked in one parent ID, for instance.)

What's still not super obvious is why these differ:

```
$ git log --no-walk --numstat 00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837 
[snip output: log message, with no diff-stats]
$ git show --numstat 00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837
[snip log message]
4       0       libavcodec/mpegaudiodecheader.c
```

If we simply add `-m` to `git log` (so that we clear the `rev->ignore_merges` flag) we get numstat diffs against both parents.  If we add `--cc` as well, however, we get the same result as `git show`:

```
$ git log -m --cc --no-walk --numstat 00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837
[snip log message]
4       0       libavcodec/mpegaudiodecheader.c
```

and a bit of thought *now* makes it clear why we see only the one file: **it's the only file that has changes from both parents.**  This is the same constraint as for any combined diff, and sure enough, replacing `--cc` with `-c` (with that same `git log`) produces the same result.

#### Bottom line, as it were

Without `-m`, `-c`, or `--cc`, `git log` prints log messages for merges, but never even attempts to show diffs of the merge commit against its parents.  Without any of those options, `git show` sets `--cc`.  This is approximately half documented.

Comment: Great, thanks, very comprehensive answer.   I checked this as correct, but I'm still a little bit confused, so I'd just like to clear this up -- `git show` by default (with the --cc option), diffs "*only files which were modified from all parents.*" (as does git log with -c or --cc)?

Looking again at the commit from case 1 (the merge commit), it appears to my tests that git show, and git log -c/--cc, as in Joseph K Strauss' answer, produce the numstat/diff with the *first parent only*.

Comment: This is the case comparing the output both with output of git log -m, using git diff --numstat to compare the commit with it's parents directly, and looking at the git log --numstat of each of the parent commits individually (I'll leave out the demo for brevity, but can include it if needed).  I think the behaviour I'm looking for is the 'only files modified from all parents' case.  It doesn't seem to me that that's what git show or git log -c/--cc is producing for this commit (and maybe an empty numstat is correct in this case), but perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Mike: the problem here is that "files modified from all parents" and "files modified from first parent" is the same set of files, for this particular commit: diff(merge,p1) => audio thing; diff(merge, p2) => many files, *including* audio thing.  To distinguish between the cases you would need a merge where, eg, diff(merge,p1) => fileA, fileB; diff(merge,p2) => fileB, fileC.  Then "all parents" is fileB only while "vs p1" or "vs p2" vary.  (Note also that `log` with *no* flags simply doesn't bother showing any diffs at all, even with `--numstat`.)

Comment: You're right.  I mistyped the grep and didn't look through the list of files hard enough.  I think I was also confused by the fact that in this case, `git show -c <commit>`, and `git show -c --numstat <commit>` are inconsistent.  The first parent has a diff of 8 added/13 removed lines, and the second has the 4 added line diff in audiothing.c (each parent modifies separate lines).  `git show -c` displays the combined diff, but adding `--numstat` makes it look like there's only a 4 line difference (which is why I thought it was looking at the first parent).  In this case, I would expect +12/-13.

Comment: Actually, I guess I would expect was an empty diff in this case, and include only *lines* that were modified from all parents (eg. lines in fileB that differ from both p1 *and* p2 (... & pn)), but I suppose maybe that level of granularity is difficult or maybe has weird edge cases, and file level granularity makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your first commit (00049f193d07cec0409069bc51d0dcb8ab9da837) is a merge. Therefore, it will assume that you do not care to see the stat for the the commit, but show will display the numstat for the diff to the first parent.

I tried to find documentation for this, but I cannot.

Comment: This would partly explain things, but `git log` and `git show` are supposed to both default to using combined diffs, including for `--numstat`.  (Add `-m` to do separate diffs against each parent.)  So it's odd that the output would change between them (it's not odd that they would omit the file entirely, it's just odd that `git show --numstat` *doesn't*).

Comment: It turns out I am subtly wrong: `git log` and `git show` choose different combined-diff options.